# Submitting a form after processing in PHP

Tags: php, post, curl, forms

we have a form that grabs a whole bunch of details and then submits it to a mail program which send an email to certain people.

I need to put some extra processing between the form and mail program which checks info from a db and then changes the form data accordingly.

I thought I would be able to use curl for this but once I do the processing I need to submit the form and have things run the way they would as if the php wasn't there and it seems I can't do this with curl.

Question is can I do this with curl? Or is there a better way to go about this. (although I can do minor changes to both the mail and form they should stay the same as much as possible).

Edit: I'm not sure what information I can put in but I'll try and simplify it.

At the moment:   form -> mail program

What I am trying to do: form -> php ->mail program

Mail program takes POST variables so what I want to do is grab the post variables, change some of them and then send them to the mail program and the previous process looks the same.

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough information to satisfactorily answer this question.

Comment: Is the mail script PHP also? Do you control it, or does the form post to a remote server?

Comment: Nah, its an application thats written in another language and I have very little control of it.

Comment: let's see if my statement is true, your `<form>` action attribute is pointing to the mail program, but you want it to point to your php file first, process it, and then you will pass this form to the mail program. Right?

Comment: Yes, it does currently but curl apparently wont then go to the page that is generated by the mail program. But an attribute was missing from curl which i wasn't aware of. Got it working using curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer was curl can do it for what I need, needed:

```
 `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Requires PHP5. Arrange all the data you need in PHP and stream out the post values.

Answer (score 0):

make the PHP file to generate a form with the attribute filled with processed value. then you use Javascript to submit the form in the end.